# How to pass parameter to the redirect method in URL helper in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I'm new to Codeigniter, and I want redirect to a controller after the validation is fall:

```
if(!validate)
{
  redirect('/poll/list');
}
```

but I need to pass a variable like `$error` to show the some error indication, but I don't know how to pass the parameter to `redirect` method in the `URL helper`, and idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [session flashdata](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) - this is exactly what it is designed for:

```
if(!validate)
{
  $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'your_error');
  redirect('/poll/list');
}
```

Then inside your poll/list function:

```
$error_msg = $this->session->flashdata('error');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly What I am looking for and +1 for the example code

Comment: Most recent URL: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score 1):

```
base url = 'http://localhost/site/'
```

**URL**    `http://localhost/site/controller/method`

```
$this->uri->segment(1) = 'controller'
$this->uri->segment(2) = 'method'
```

Now check the below case also

```
base url = 'http://testsite/test/site/'
```

**URL**   `http://testsite/test/site/controller/method`

```
$this->uri->segment(1) = 'controller'
$this->uri->segment(2) = 'method'
```

Pass your message

`http://testsite/test/site/controller/method/meesage`

and use 
`$this->uri->segment(3)`

You can use session also instead passing message through `URL`..